# String Formatting columns in Haskell without Text.Printf

Tags: string, haskell, formatting, output, printf

I am new to Haskell. I am at the last part of a school project. I have to take tuples and print them to an outfile and separate them by a tab column. So (709,4226408), (12965,4226412) and (5,4226016) should have and output of

```
709     4226408
12965   4226412
5       4226016
```

What I have been trying to do is this:

```
genOutput :: (Int, Int) -> String
genOutput (a,b) = (show a) ++ "\t" ++ (show b)
```

And this gives outputs like:

```
"709\t4226408"
"12965\t4226412"
"5\t4226016"
```

There are 3 things wrong with this. 1) Quotes still appear in the output. 2) The \t tab does not actually become a tab space. .Whenever I try to make an actual tab for the "" it just comes out as a " " space. 3) They are not aligned into columns like the above example. I know Text.Printf exists but we are not allowed to import anything other than:

```
import System.IO
import Data.List
import System.Environment
```

Comment: How are you printing the strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's the output you get from GHCi I guess? Try to use `putStrLn` instead:

```hs
Prelude> genOutput (1,42)                                      
"1\t42"                                                        
                                                               
Prelude> putStrLn $ genOutput (1,42)                    
1       42
```

---

#### Why is that?

If you tell GHCi to evaluate an expression it will do so and (more or less) output it using `show` - `show` is designed to work with `read` and will usually output a value as if you would input it directly into Haskell. For a String that will include escape sequences and the `"`s

Now using `putStrLn` it will take the string and print it to *stdout* as you would expect.

---

#### Using `print`

Another reason could be that you use `print` to output your value - `print` is `show` + `putStrLn` so it'll show the values first re-introducing the escapes (as GHCi would) - so if you use `print` change it to `putStrLn` if you are using `String`s